# Multitouch screen not detected on Asus Taichi 21DH71

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch

I just bought this Ultrabook "Asus Taichi 21 DH71".

This has Intel 3rd generation i7 processor and 4gb ram with 256 gb SSD. The main feature is that it is a hybrid machine. Naming it has dual screens. When the lid is closed it can be used as a tablet and when lid open it can be used as a notebook.

This machine can also be used with the two screens on at the same time. I used ubuntu many years ago and loved it. But I never tried any linux later.

My questions are

1. Does the new version of Ubuntu support the Multitouch interface?
2. Will it work specifically on this machine?
3. Will Ubuntu support gestures on multi touchpad?

Update 2/22/2013

I did try the latest 64bit Ubuntu(12.10) from live usb and noticed that it couldn't detect the tablet screen. Everything else worked seamlessly.

Do you guys think the tablet screen would be detected if I make a complete installation on to the notebook?

Please help guys..

Comment: Related: [How do I make a multitouch touchscreen working on ubuntu 12.10?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/259576/how-do-i-make-a-multitouch-touchscreen-working-on-ubuntu-12-10)

Comment: Eliha, your link link to an answer who link to her. PARADOX

Answer (score 3):

Execute `lsusb` commmand, find your touchscreen ID in the output (looks like `04e7:0022`) and check if it's present in this list of supported multitouch devices:

http://lii-enac.fr/en/architecture/linux-input/multitouch-devices.html

If it's not you can try enabling it and reporting compatibility here:

http://lii-enac.fr/en/architecture/linux-input/multitouch-howto.html

Comment: Please avoid posting the same answer in [more than one place](http://askubuntu.com/a/260721/22949). When tempted to do so, typically: (1) the answer should be customized to account for what is different about the different questions, (2) one question should be flagged for closure as a duplicate of another question (you can flag posts with [15 reputation](http://askubuntu.com/privileges/flag-posts)), (3) the answer should really be a comment, **or** (4) the answer should be posted in the most appropriate place, and one-line comments posted on the other questions summarizing and linking to it.

Comment: How do I download the driver? how to install? i found the neccesry driver, but what now?

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever try to use this enac.fr site to really install a touch monitor?
I mean without being a ubuntu-linux-freak with at least some years of compiling kernel experience?
This is just a question to install a monitor!! 
A monitor with usb-input to linux just like a touchpad or a mouse - nothing else. 
Does this really mean recompiling a linux kernel to install a device like a keyboard, a mouse, a touchpad or a similar "simple" touch-monitor?

Do we have to install git, gcc and a working compile chain to connect a touch-monitor?

Answer (score 0):

Touchscreen works in Arch Linux; so, I think Ubuntu may be configured to work with it too. But screen itself doesn't work, maybe you should try enable both screens in Windows, then reboot to Linux and configure screens as usual.

Answer (score 0):

I just got myTaichi 21 yesterday, and installed Ubuntu 16.04 on it. Here is what I have to say:

- Only if I power up the laptop with lid closed, it will power up the touch screen
- If I power the laptop up with the lid open, only the inner screen will be powered on, however, the Ubuntu will detect the touch screen properly, and allow to configure it. Also the touch input works. You can actually move windows to and from the touch screen, just that, it is not physically turned on.

Since the touch screen becomes powered upon powering up with lid closed before any Linux loader shows up, I suspect that it may be BIOS that initiates that. But I would think there has to be a way to manually, from command line, send some control command to the motherboard to power it on/off later on when in logged into the Ubuntu. I just couldn't find a way, I tried:

- xset dpms
- echoing things into /sys/bus/usb/devices/... tree

There ahs to be some control command that can be sent to the screen but I've yet to find it. So far at least I can poweroff and on again with lid closed, which will make both screens available to me.