# How do I make a multitouch touchscreen working on ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, multi-touch, touchscreen

I have a multitouch touchscreen with USB interface.
It works fine on android platform.
And I am working on making it to support multitouch gesture on ubuntu 12.10.
However, it acts as a single touchscreen.
Does any document or example could be probvided to make it work as a multitouch touchscreen on ubuntu 12.10 ?

Comment: Is it a duplicate? That question is about making the touch-screen work at all, whereas this questioner has the screen working in single-touch mode, but not multi-touch.